# how to calculate area of polygon on a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to calculate area of polygon on a map?

Requirements:we can calculate area of polygon on a map ie,

we have coordinates of polygon that will find area of polygon.
area will be acres and hectare

```
coordinates is: [
    [10.075854059674523, 76.32832467556],
    [10.079825860518895, 76.33338868618011],
    [10.076234340596953, 76.33806645870209],
    [10.07065684212598, 76.33806645870209],
    [10.068924417668397, 76.33175790309906]
]
```

Comment: [From Google-ing: area polygon coordinates](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the formula of `polygon`,

```
Area of ploygon = [(x1y2-x2y1) + (x2y3-x3y2) + .... + (x(n-1)yn - y(n-1)xn)]/2
```

Try,

```
var arr=[
    [10.075854059674523, 76.32832467556],
    [10.079825860518895, 76.33338868618011],
    [10.076234340596953, 76.33806645870209],
    [10.07065684212598, 76.33806645870209],
    [10.068924417668397, 76.33175790309906]
];
var sum=0;
for(var i=0,l=arr.length-1;i<l;i++){
    sum+=(arr[i][0]*arr[i+1][1]-arr[i+1][0]*arr[i][1]);
}
alert('The Area of Ploygon is:'+(sum/2));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/EB867/)

Comment: Unit of `co-ordinates` is what `hectare` or `acres`?

Comment: I dont know , i am creating this coordinates on a map using leaflets

Comment: You must know, the area unit is whatever your co-ordinates unit.

Comment: units of coordinates is decimal(DD). please help me this will convert to hectares and acres

Comment: please respond my reply

Comment: `Decimal` is not an unit. It is a number, or we can say representation of real number. Assume your co-ordinates in hectare then above code will give you area in `hectares`, or if you assume the co-ordinates in `acres` then above will give you area in `acres`.